# Math graduate school applications and personal hardships

Tags: soft-question, career, advice

This question is on mathematics, career, and personal life.

I.) Assumptions.

i.) Suppose that I am a Junior in college majoring in mathematics at a top research institution in the U.S. I have "mostly" good grades in mathematics (say, around 2/3 of my grades are A's or A-'s), but I have some B's and B+'s. I've taken a good number of graduate level courses with at least half of them A or A-'s.

ii.) Earlier in my college career, there was a noticeable dip in my grades (A's becoming B's and B+'s) due to personal issues.

iii.) My goals:

- (Short term:) enroll in a top pure math graduate program in the U.S. (ideally a top 6 institution) where there is a strong research community in my field as well as other fields in mathematics which may be helpful to my own research or broadening my perspective.
- (Long term:) become a professor in pure mathematics at a top 30 institution (or equivalent) studying geometric topology or some related field.

II.) **My Questions**:

a.) Is it appropriate to talk about personal matters in one's personal statements or to have such a discussion in letters of recommendation, if it has negatively impacted one's academic performance?

b.) What are graduate school admission committees' views in regards to personal hardships? I know the short answer to this is "it depends," so I would appreciate getting the various viewpoints available on the MathOverflow community. I am sure it also depends on the school; school-specific viewpoints would be much appreciated.

Comment: this is not an answer to your two questions, hence a comment: I have found it counterproductive to take "becoming a professor" as a goal in life, in particular at an early stage of one's career as a scientist; I would approach graduate school as an opportunity to learn skills that will serve you well wherever life takes you, and explore a great variety of career options.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this question is of interest for an international audience.

Comment: Investors (people who are willing to spend resources in some area) are looking for a good chance of return.  Having turned your situation around is good, but investors are willing to look at someone who is resilient enough to try turning it around, who knows they are resilient, and who can communicate that.  If you can portray a positive and realistic future and attitude, that gives the investor confidence.  Gerhard "Explain Turnaround, But Don't Dwell" Paseman, 2020.06.13.

Comment: @YCor, I don't think it's for MO at all, but much more for [AcademiaSE](http://academia.stackexchange.com); but, setting that aside, why should it *not* be of interest to an international audience?  (The only location-specific things that I can see are two mentions of the US, which could probably even be deleted without changing the substance of the question.)

Comment: @Carlo Beenakker Thank you for the advice. I guess what I should have said instead was that "I intend to become a mathematician working in academia." Following Thurson's advice (https://mathoverflow.net/posts/44213/revisions), my ultimate goal is to deepen mankind's (and hence my own) understanding of mathematics. (I just didn't think this was worth mentioning since it is )

Comment: @LSpice The reason why I wanted to hear from MO is because different fields in academia seems to have different cultures. (e.g. at least to my understanding, experimental physics seems to care less about an applicants grades and put more emphasis on his/her capacity to do research.) I wanted to know hear the math community's answer to my question.

Comment: @Gerhard Paseman Your comment seems very plausible. In practice, to what extent do admission committees value such resilience? Based on what I hear from people it's mostly about grades, GRE scores, and how much a well-known faculty member recommends you.

Comment: @MattF. Thanks. I just made the post shorter.

Comment: My only experience with admission committees was applying to Berkeley.  It is possible I got admitted in to graduate school by good fortune, even though I left undergraduate study five years earlier.  And stellar recommendation letters are good too.  However, I wrote a personal essay where I mustered all my confidence and talked about using my industry experience to help me in my graduate studies.  I think I would not have been accepted if I did not display that kind of attitude. Again, acknowledge, but don't dwell.  Gerhard "Believe That You Are Worthy" Paseman, 2020.06.13.

Comment: I find the focus on "top N" a bit unhealthy

Comment: You set your goals too high, which is OK if you don't get unhappy by not achieving them. In order to get into a top graduate school you need to be in the top few percent (1%, 2%, 5% etc., depending on the school). Your grades will not justify this as the majority of applicants are straight A's. If you have interesting research papers (preferably with no co-author), or have showed extraordinary talent to your recommenders, that might counterbalance it. I suggest that you apply to at least 30 graduate schools. Some schools do ask recommenders to mention special circumstances they are aware of.

Comment: My two cents: one, I think a brief explanation of why your grades dropped would be helpful to the admissions committee, as long as it doesn't get too self-involved or whiny. Two, many stellar mathematicians didn't go to a top graduate school. Getting into a top school is good for your ego but it isn't vitally important.

Comment: @NikWeaver There are surely practical benefits to getting into a top school, right? You'll probably do better on the postdoc market, get more connections, and be exposed to different areas of mathematics than lesser known schools. (For instance, when famous foreign scholars come to give talks, I assume most of them are in the famous schools.) Here, by "famous," I mean people whose research is gaining a lot of attention at that point in time.

Comment: To have a successful research career in math there is no need to go to top grad school. The chance of becoming a top mathematician is very low - I would not obsess about it. But if you are, I suggest the following experiment. Write the list of invited ICM speakers for several recent ICMs. Go to math genealogy site, and see where they got the PhD from (compare with the total number of PhDs from that school). If you are focused on US market, run a similar test with a list of junior faculty at top US schools.

Answer (score 4):

This question was asked a while ago, but never got an answer. The comments focused on how a goal of "getting into a top 6 PhD program" followed by a "top 30 professorship" was a potentially unhealthy goal. I agree with that, so this answer is aimed at anyone applying to grad school, even beyond the "top 6." Let's start with question (a), regarding personal statements.

**Yes, you can use your personal statement to explain relevant personal hardships, how they affected your performance, what you learned from them, and how you've grown.**

[Here](https://www.swarthmore.edu/sites/default/files/assets/documents/mathematics-statistics/MathGradSchool.pdf) is some general advice about grad school applications, from Swarthmore. Their advice item (2) is to do as well as possible on outside measurements like the GRE, REUs, study abroad, and Putnam exam. Their (3) is to take as many challenging math courses as possible (it sounds like the OP did this). Challenging courses and good letters of recommendation matter more than perfect grades. Their (5) concerns applying for grants to fund your PhD, (6) is about letters of recommendation, (7) is about your personal statement, and (8) is about emailing professors at places you apply.

The advice from Swarthmore is backed up by web pages of various PhD programs, e.g., [this one from UMD](https://www-math.umd.edu/graduate/80-math/graduate/539-frequently-asked-questions-about-the-graduate-admissions-process.html), [previous MO questions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15848/what-to-look-for-in-applicants-to-graduate-programs-in-mathematics), [MSE questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46142/ph-d-admission-in-the-us-uk-how-is-an-m-sc-regarded), and [advice on academia.SE](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/10931/planning-for-grad-school). The idea that it's ok to have some Bs, especially in hard courses, appears in those links and is confirmed [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/55882/do-graduate-schools-care-more-about-my-grades-in-math-courses-or-my-general-gpa) and [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/142066/gpa-for-phd-application).

Let's turn to question (b) regarding how graduate school admissions committees view personal hardships.

**Yes, done right, your history of overcoming a personal hardship can become a strength in your application.**

The [last link above](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/142066/gpa-for-phd-application) also includes advice to use your personal statement to present yourself as a "whole package." A candidate can use their personal statement to strengthen their application if they explain (briefly) the personal hardship and how they learned from it and bounced back from adversity. You can find more advice [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/10518/improving-my-phd-application-for-math-programs) regarding the personal statement and using it to tie together your record. There have also been [previous advice threads about using the personal statement](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/31079/should-i-explain-to-the-graduate-admission-committee-why-i-am-older-than-most-pr). The general theme is that, if written convincingly, the personal statement can definitely help you, especially if it's related to your motivation, determination, grit, resilience, and current ability to succeed in their program. The story in that thread (and responses to it) show that for sure the personal statement and overcoming hardships, can play in your favor as the applicant.

The advice at all these sources consistently says to keep the story short and to the point. Aim for around two pages for the personal statement. Since [letters of recommendation are consistently put among the top criteria](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/31609/is-having-a-too-good-to-be-true-recommendation-bad) (whereas, personal statements are not), it might be wise to talk to at least one letter writer about your concerns that the grade dip will harm your chances of being accepted, and to explain to them what happened. You can't really tell them how to write their letter, but if they agree with you during that conversation, odds are that they will add a sentence or two backing up your story and expressing their confidence regarding you despite this previous hiccup.

Lastly, I want to re-emphasize the point made in some of the comments that setting goals like "being accepted to a top N university" is not wise for mental health, and is not necessary for career success. Certainly it's true that there's a prestige bias in mathematics (happy to share links to published research that proves this if you want). However, the advice on MO, MSE, and academia.SE is consistent on the point that it's better to choose a field of study that you love (instead of whichever you think might best help you get a job), choose an advisor you have a good relationship with (instead of the most famous / influential advisor), and choose a graduate program where you can be fulfilled, productive, and happy (e.g., taking into account the location, culture, other students, your romantic partner, etc.) instead of whichever is the most prestigious. In math, we're so used to optimization problems, but in life, it's important to optimize on a number of different fronts simultaneously (and, honestly, for happiness, it's better to take an attitude of "satisficing," e.g., "this job might not be the best I can get, but it's good enough for me and I'm happy with it"). Constantly climbing and defining your self worth in terms of something as fickle as external rankings of your university, is not a recipe for a happy life. Good luck with your applications, PhD experience, and life!

Comment: Just to comment to thank David for his service in writing down answers to these questions, which may help many others, especially young people, in the future.